# nHibernate 3.0 and Oracle XMLTYPE

Tags: xml, oracle, nhibernate

How to map an Oracle SYS.XMLTYPE in nHibernate.
Or does nHibernate 3.0 has an built in type for it?

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring your property as `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`; NHibernate has default types to deal with those.

Comment: I've tried both and got the following error: "Unsupported Oracle data type USERDEFINED encountered"

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14306/appendixa.htm --> the .net type should be Char[], but that doesn't work

Comment: According to that, it can be mapped to string too (which should work with NH's xdoc)... It's not very clear. When do you get that error?

Comment: I got the error when I run the application, not at compile time.

Comment: when **in your code**? What is your code doing when that error happens?

Comment: when I open the session (.OpenSession())